# Application restarts when calling FB.ActivateApp after closing AdMob interstitial

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, admob

After integrating AdMob to my Unity3D game, the game restarts after closing the interstitial on Android only (working ok in iOS). I've narrowed it down and found out that after closing the interstitial, the OnApplicationPause method is called and there I had a call to FB.ActivateApp. Removing the FB.ActivateApp call solves the issue, but I have no idea why. Anyone has idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the stacktrace that you will find in your log. It will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating Facebook SDK to the latest version (6.1.2).